# Creating object inside the same Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, lombok

Below code is creating object of Addressdto(inside Address) inside its own class,as per my understanding here object is creating infinitely,please help me understand what exactly below code is intended to do.

```java
public class AddressDto {
    public static Address from(AddressDto addressDto) {
        return Address.builder()
            .addressLine(addressDto.getAddressLine())
            .landmark(addressDto.getLandmark())
            .city(addressDto.getCity())
            .state(addressDto.getState())
            .country(addressDto.getCountry())
            .zipcode(addressDto.getZipcode())
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: In your AddressDto, you have a method that takes an instance of AddressDto, and returns an instance of Address with the same data. it's a basic conversion from type A to type B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there are two classes used here, `Address` class and `AddressDTO` class. An `Address` object is being made inside the `from` method. The data needed to build the `Address` object is retrieved from the `AddressDTO`. The `from` method is only converting a `AddressDTO` object into `Address` object.

Comment: Actually, there is one class, there are instances of two classes.

Comment: @Stultuske What I mean is there are 2 different classes used.

Comment: is from a special kind of keyword?

Comment: @vernol no it is not, it is just an ordinary method name, you can change it to any name you like

Comment: @vernol if it was, it couldn't be used as the name of a method. from is just the name of your method